# Why is axios returning a promise?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have this

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const fetchData = async () => {
    const URL = 'url here'
    const { data } = await axios.get(URL)
    return data
}
```

At this point, I get the data I want, an array of objects

```
Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

Yet in another file when I use the `fetchData` function:

```
const DisplayPeople = () => {
    const data = fetchData()
    console.log(data);
    return (
        <div>DisplayPeople</div>
    )
}
```

Here, what I get is instead:

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
   <state>: "fulfilled"
   <value>: Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
   <prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }
```

Why is it like this? I just want to get the same result as I get in the `fetchData` function

Comment: Yes? `fetchData` is an async function, so `const data = fetchData()` returns a Promise (that's what the `async` keyword makes functions do) whereas `const data = await fetchData()` will get you the actual data.

Comment: Yes, it is an async function, which is why in the first code I used async/await, and then I simply return the data. So if I use the function elsewhere, I need to use async/await yet again? Even though in the first code I have used async/await and am simply returning the data?

Comment: Except you're _not_ "simply returning the data", you are returning that data _asynchronously_ through a promise. That's what the `async` part means. You're not returning data the traditional synchronous way through the function call itself, the return _has_ to be awaited (either using `await`, or by explicitly using the promise-handling `....then().catch()` chain).

Answer (score 1):

You get a promise return in the second case

> ```
> const DisplayPeople = () => {
>   const data = fetchData()
>   console.log(data);
>   return (
>     <div>DisplayPeople</div>
>   )
> }
> ```

because your `fetchData()` is an `async` function. And all `async` functions return a promise, even something like

```
async function get5() {
  return 5;
}
```

So unless you `await fetchData()`, you'll get a promise instead of the value of the settled promise that it returns.

Comment: Yes, it is an async function, which is why in the first code I used async/await, and then I simply return the data. So if I use the function elsewhere, I need to use async/await yet again? Even though in the first code I have used async/await and am simply returning the data?

Comment: Yes. You must `await` the `async` function, always.  Unless you do so, you will alway get a promise rather than its settled value.